# Fatal errors to undefined function in theme 404.php file

Tags: php, themes, fatal-error

Recently, I started seeing the below errors for certain WordPress themes. Any idea what this is about? I’ve not made any changes to these themes or their child themes in recent weeks.

These are errors I am seeing on our GoDaddy-hosted Multisite (iTheme2 theme):

`[16-Mar-2017 16:48:08 UTC] PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_template_part() in /home/xxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/themes/itheme2/404.php on line 1
[23-Mar-2017 14:08:21 UTC] PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_template_part() in /home/xxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/themes/itheme2/404.php on line 1`

These are errors I am seeing on our GoDaddy-hosted Multisite (Twenty Eleven theme):

`[20-Mar-2017 04:23:35 UTC] PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_header() in /home/xxxxx/public_html/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/404.php on line 10
[24-Mar-2017 07:33:31 UTC] PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_header() in /home/xxxxx/public_html/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/404.php on line 10
[24-Mar-2017 18:56:45 UTC] PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_header() in /home/iamonenet/public_html/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/404.php on line 10`

These are errors I’m seeing on our SiteGround-hosted site (iTheme2):

`[18-Mar-2017 13:25:20 CST6CDT] PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_template_part() in /home/xxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/themes/itheme2/404.php on line 1
[23-Mar-2017 16:45:41 CST6CDT] PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_template_part() in /home/xxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/themes/itheme2/404.php on line 1`

I also started the same thing on the GoDaddy-hosted Multisite for the Divi theme and on another SiteGround hosted site using the Divi theme.

I've posted to the respective theme forums but haven't heard back yet.

Thanks for any thoughts you can share about this.

Update:
I just noticed some similar errors for the index.php file. And the same errors start appearing when I actually visit the index.php and 404.php files in my browser; it also seems that errors start showing up (maybe) when our security scanners from SiteLock, SiteGround, and ManageWP run. Could those security scanners be causing the errors?

Comment: Does any theme work?

Comment: Does each site use a common set of plugins? Does a visit to a non-existent address cause the error every time? It almost looks to me like some plugin is somehow interacting with error page requests and breaking WordPress's loading process.

Comment: @belinus, all the themes work.

Comment: @bosco, yes, they all pretty much use the same plugins, with some minor differences depending on whether special functions needed to be fulfilled on some of the sites. I just tried triggering the errors by visiting nonexistent pages, but no errors happened.

Comment: I just noticed some similar errors for the index.php file. And the same errors start appearing when I actually visit the index.php and 404.php files in my browser; it also seems that errors start showing up (maybe) when our security scanners from SiteLock, SiteGround, and ManageWP run. Could those security scanners be causing the errors?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you or someone is directly accessing/loading the theme template files. `get_template_part` and `get_header` are core WP functions and only work within WP framework.

Comment: Thanks, Irene. I don't think I'm personally doing this. In what scenario, do you think, could something like this happen? What's strange is that these errors only occur on some of the sites I have (hosted on SiteGround cloud hosting and on that multisite hosted on GoDaddy), but doesn't happen on my other sites that are using the same themes as the ones throwing the errors (GoDaddy Managed WordPress sites). Any ideas?

Comment: If you are not personally doing this then most likely your sites on SiteGround are under attack. Check the other files too, not just the themes. Check for unusual files and unusual contents inserted. Unusual contents are usually hidden and not visible in the eye. Or better yet, use google to check your sites for possible hack -:

Comment: I've checked my sites using Sucuri's site scanner, I'm using one of THE best security plugins on all the sites (BulletProof Security Pro), and I've just checked the sites using ManageWP's Security Check. Nothing is pointing to an attack... nothing malicious found.